# Manual approvals for stages in Azure Devops pipelines (YAML)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a stage that uses 6 deployment jobs that can either deploy to dev, staging or production depending on specific conditions.

For deploying to production, I'd like to add manual approvals. I am aware that deployment jobs can specify environments on which you can add manual approvals, but I'd like to approve the entire stage and not each individual deployment job. This way, I can approve the stage once and all 6 deployment jobs can run at once, instead of having to approve 6 times.

Is this possible? The documentation says [it should be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-approvals), but it doesn't say how. Besides, in the [YAML schema for stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-stages), it doesn't look like you can specify environments inside stages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no such a built-in feature to approve entire stage in YAML. We can only [Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) for the environments. The documentation you mentioned is also indicated that this is commonly used to control deployments to production **environments**.

However, there's already a [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/567845/add-pre-and-post-deployment-approvals-for-multi-st.html) to request the feature. You could vote and add your comments for the suggestion ticket to achieve that in future release.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the [ManualValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task could help you there. Using dependsOn will allow all other jobs to complete before final approval.

Example:

```
jobs:  
  - job: waitForValidation
    dependsOn: 'previousJobName'
    displayName: Wait for external validation  
    pool: server    
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:   
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          test@test.com
          example@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'reject'
```

Comment: what happens on "resume" after timeout? Is the behavior concretely acceptable in practice?

Comment: I changed onTimeout to reject as it's a more appropriate outcome - nothing progresses any further